# React: how do I add transition animation to a component after it is mounted to the screen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a component that should show up from `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1` with `transition: opacity 200ms;`. I use CSS and classes to control this. The idea is that as soon as the component gets mounted to the screen we add a `classname` `entered` on it.

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}

.box.entered {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```js
export default function App() {
  const mounted = useRef();
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    mounted.current = true;
    return () => {
      mounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);

  return <div className={`box ${mounted.current ? "entered" : ""}`}></div>;
}
```

here I used a ref to detect whether or not this component has been mounted. but it seems like it is not working fine. I guess it was because when `ref.current` changed from `false` to `true`, it doesn't retrigger a re-render. I know that I probably can use another local state called `mounted` to update the `classname` instead of using a ref but I wonder if there is a better way to do it?

Here is the live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-bardeen-l8y7p?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a state here nested of ref, state give you ability to make re-render updates for all place is used, and you dont need here to clean function -base on your case-, since its will not trigger else if its leave...

any way, I change the code to be like a state and its work perfect, and you can check your demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-waterfall-feyuy?file=/src/App.js)

```
export default function App() {
  const [isEnterd, setIsEnterd] = useState(false);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setIsEnterd(true);

    return () => {
      setIsEnterd(false);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div className={`box ${isEnterd ? "entered" : ""}`}></div>;
}
```

note: since you are use the useLayoutEffect you must now this:

> The signature is identical to useEffect, but it fires synchronously
> after all DOM mutations. Use this to read layout from the DOM and
> synchronously re-render. Updates scheduled inside useLayoutEffect will
> be flushed synchronously, before the browser has a chance to paint.

Answer (score 0):

The key issue is that update useRef value doesn't trigger a re-render.
If you add a display on the page, you will see the value of mounted.current is undefined.
To prove it, you can simply set the state inside useLayoutEffect hook, it will trigger another render and your code will work. You don't need to use the state value. Just setting it is enough.